# How to deploy a release after changing the configurations?

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter, devops, kubernetes-helm, jupyterhub

I have had jhub released in my cluster successfully. I then changed the config to pull another docker image as stated in the [documentation](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup-jupyterhub.html).

This time, while running the same old command:

```
# Suggested values: advanced users of Kubernetes and Helm should feel
# free to use different values.
RELEASE=jhub
NAMESPACE=jhub

helm upgrade --install $RELEASE jupyterhub/jupyterhub \
  --namespace $NAMESPACE  \
  --version=0.8.2 \
  --values jupyter-hub-config.yaml
```

where the `jupyter-hub-config.yaml` file is:

```
proxy:
  secretToken: "<a secret token>"
singleuser:
  image:
    # Get the latest image tag at:
    # https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook/tags/
    # Inspect the Dockerfile at:
    # https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/datascience-notebook/Dockerfile
    name: jupyter/datascience-notebook
    tag: 177037d09156
```

I get the following problem:

```
UPGRADE FAILED
ROLLING BACK
Error: "jhub" has no deployed releases
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: "jhub" has no deployed releases
```

I then deleted the namespace via `kubectl delete ns/jhub` and the release via `helm delete --purge jhub`. Again tried this command in vain, again the same error.

I read few GH issues and found that either the YAML file was invalid or that the `--force` flag worked. However, in my case, none of these two are valid.

I expect to make this release and also learn how to edit the current releases.

Note: As you would find in the aforementioned documentation, there is a pvc created.

Comment: Is this case is still valid?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I was trying to update my `config.yaml` file in GKE. Actually what worked for me is to redo these steps:

1. run `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/helm/master/scripts/get | bash`
2. `helm init --service-account tiller --history-max 100 --wait`
3. [OPTIONAL] `helm version` to verify that you have a similar output as the documentation
4. Add repo

```
helm repo add jupyterhub https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart/
helm repo update
```

5. Run upgrade

```
RELEASE=jhub
NAMESPACE=jhub

helm upgrade $RELEASE jupyterhub/jupyterhub \
  --namespace $NAMESPACE  \
  --version=0.9.0 \
  --values config.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

After changes in kubeconfig the next solution worked for me

```
helm init --tiller-namespace=<ns> --upgrade
```

Works with kubectl 1.10.0 and helm 2.3.0. I guess this upgrades tiller to compatible helm version.

Don't forget to set KUBECONFIG variable before use this comman - this step itself may solve your issue if you didn't do this after changing your kubeconfig.

```
export KUBECONFIG=<*.kubeconfig>
```

In my case in the config cluster.server field has been changed, but context.name and current-context fields I left the same as in the previous config, not sure if it matters. And I faced the same issue on the firs try to deploy new release with helm, but after first successful deploy it's enough to change KUBECONFIG variable.
I hope it helps.

Comment: try explaining your answer a bit more

Answer (score 0):

Added the following to my gCloud. I run it everytime I update my `config.yaml` file. Make sure to be connected to the correct Kubernetes cluster before running.

`update.sh`

```sh
# Installs Helm.
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/helm/master/scripts/get | bash

# Make Helm aware of the JupyterHub Helm chart repo.
helm repo add jupyterhub https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart/
helm repo update

# Re-installs the chart configured by your config.yaml.
RELEASE=jhub
JUPYTERHUB_VERSION=0.9.0
helm upgrade $RELEASE jupyterhub/jupyterhub \
  --version=${JUPYTERHUB_VERSION} \
  --values config.yaml
```